# What's a word for "always winning"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that can describe something or someone that always seems to win when a challenge arises?

Example:

> JP Morgan Chase is **BLANK** in the banking industry.

Comment: Triumphant, possibly ? Or 'a front-runner' ?

Comment: Lucky?  Skilled?  Successful?  Pre-eminent? Thanks for providing the sample sentence, but it would help if you filled in the sense and connotation you want.

Comment: Gladstone Gander?

Answer (score 2):

The word I'd use is **dominating**:

> If something is dominating, that means it has a powerful and commanding position. If your team is *dominating* on the basketball court, you're not only winning, you're outplaying your opponents.

Also:

> most powerful, important, or influential
>   <sub>[Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/dominating)</sub>

For an example of it in use see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Four_(banking)):

> The Big Four is the colloquial name for the four main banks in several countries, where the banking industry is dominated by just four institutions and where the phrase has gained currency.

Comment: Dominating is also commonly used in video games and e-sports to describe players or teams that are currently undefeated / on a winning streak.

Answer (score 0):

"Invincible" or "indomitable," to name two.

Comment: Hi Kurt, the system is likely to flag your answer for deletion as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on this site is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. You can [edit] your answer to avoid the risk of deletion - for example, adding a dictionary definition for the proposed words, linked to the source. For further guidance, see [answer]. Make sure you also take the **[Tour]** :-)

Answer (score 0):

This may be too simple of a word for the type of sentence you are constructing but how about **a winner**? Literally defined as

> one that wins